# Selenium IE Automation

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium

I'm a beginner in C# and automation. I want to try automate IE with Selenium and NUnit. I was able to lunch IE and navigate to google.com. But from some reason the prog don't find the elementID. Therefore I can't "send keys" to the field. My other problem is how do I submit a form that has no ID or Name.

Here is the code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Internal;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
   public class Class1
   {
      public IWebDriver driver;
      public string baseUrl;

      [SetUp]
      public void Setup() 
      {  
         baseUrl ="https://www.google.com";
         driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
      }
      [Test]
      public void TestCase1() 
      {
         driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl);
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
         driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq")).SendKeys("WhatIsMyIP");
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
         driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfba")).Click();
      }
      [TearDown]
      public void TearDown() { }

   }
}
```

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: using the default IE11

Comment: Are you pulling those ID's directly from the page mark-up using the built-in IE developer tools?

Comment: To be honest, you aren't going to have much luck with Selenium and IE11. It doesn't support it. Although I am unsure if it's the true reason for your issues here, it's something to note that Selenium simply doesn't support IE11 yet. Does the situation and problem change when you downgrade to IE10?

Comment: I'm currently try in IE 10 , and still the same , I fail on finding elements in the browser

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue before with google search.  The thing that happens is, as your script sends the keys to get textbox, the "smart search" thing from google comes up, and the element disappears.

Try this, this should work.

```
[Test]
public void TestCase1() 
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl);
    driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("WhatIsMyIP");
    driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnG")).Click();
}
```

Observe it for yourself. Perform a search, and watch the DOM.

Comment: also, take those explicit waits out! :|

Comment: still not working , this is what I get           ClassLibrary1.Class1.TestCase1:
    OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException : Unable to find element on     closed window

Comment: @Light_User - look at the exception; are you sure IE is open and has focus?

Comment: it is opening and navigating to the URL but fails on the find element

Comment: What id are you trying to find the element with?  `By.Name("q")` or what you had originally?

Comment: this is what I find when I search for the ID or name <input name="q" class="gbqfif" id="gbqfq" style="left: e="off" value=""/>